# Custom validation Message not working for empty field + Contact from 7

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

Am using Contact Form 7 latest version (5.6.3) on our site and when we try to add custom validation using hooks, it doesn’t work for empty field validation. The hooks work fine when we roll back the plugin version to 5.5.6.1.

Here am attaching the screenshot of the forms. this is a screenshot for version 5.6.3 https://snipboard.io/cSusk3.jpg and this is for version 5.5.6.1 https://snipboard.io/obIpS9.jpg.

Please Check the empty field value error message. Please add this code to your site and check it. The difference between the latest version and version 5.5.6.1 can be seen then.

```
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_text', 'custom_text_validation', 1, 2);
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_text*', 'custom_text_validation', 1, 2);
function custom_text_validation($result, $tag) {
    $type = $tag->type;
    $name = $tag->name;
    if($name == 'Name') {
        $value = $_POST['Name'];
         
          if($value==''){
            
            $result->invalidate($tag, "Please enter your name.");
        }
    }
 return $result;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it's confusing as to why your general function didn't work. I've written other `$result->invalidate` functions, and they all work, but testing yours did not.  This is what I came up with, but what happens is that if there's other `text` field errors their error message won't show until the `Please enter your name` message is cleared. This to me doesn't seem like a big problem.

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_text', 'custom_text_validation', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_text*', 'custom_text_validation', 10, 2 );

function custom_text_validation( $result, $tag ) {
    if ( 'Name' === $tag->name && empty( $_POST['Name'] ) ) {
        $result = new WPCF7_Validation();
        $result->invalidate( $tag, __( 'Please enter your name.' ) );
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Hello,

Thank you for sharing your code. It seems to be working. However, clicking outside of the field causes another issue. When I do not fill out the first field and just fill out the second field, and then click outside, then the default mandatory message appears. What can I do to fix that? I would appreciate your assistance.

Thanks

Comment: You must have some other jquery acting on your page then

Comment: Can you please help me to solve that using  jquery?

Comment: these are the fields:
Name,Phone,Message

Comment: is there any way to remove the on blur validation from contact from 7 ?